# Parsing either font style or block of paragraph in GATE

Tags: java, nlp, gate, transducer

I have a word document. I need to match particular table section or heading section of it using GATE. I thought if there were any steps from where we can first check any font size or font style of the heading and then match rest of the content till next heading pattern repeats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*GATE* has only a limited support for *MS Word* documents provided by the *Apache Tika* and *Apache POI* libraries. I do not know about any free alternative... We have developed our own plugin (`gate.DocumentFormat`) for this purpose in my company, but it is not available for the outside by now.

You can try to **convert** your word documents **to HTML** by some other tool (e.g. using directly the MS Word, OpenOffice, **docx4j** or others - try google `docx to html` -- you will see many results) and then process the HTML documents in GATE instead. You will see all the formatting available in the `Original markups` annotation set.

Comment: thanks @dedek, I will try going forward with your suggestion and get back to you